# how do i set get response from one jersey API into another API using jersey

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I am new to this jersey thing. My query is that I am sending I want to access response of on API which lies in some remote server into my own web service.
I am using following code

```
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/TestJersey/api/verify");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println(out);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner((Readable) out);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            buf.append(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
        }
        scanner.close();
        String responseContent = buf.toString();            
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseContent);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);return Response.status(200)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                .entity(jsonObject)
                .build();
```

I can call the web service but in response JSON object I am getting a null value. Where I need, get a JSON array. Please Help

Comment: Jersey is a *JAX-RS* (REST) compliant implementation. You should probably check the doc and address your jersey server using the jersey client (via the `Builder` class). Check the jersey doc https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html there are numerous examples. This will avoid the boilerplate code where you deserialize the response (client does it for you) and it will probably point you to the correct issue when addressing the remote REST API.

Comment: thanks for the help but i am still unable to reflect the

conn.setRequestProperty("x-api-key", "tD4TDMn2jIxb4DZS08jcpL6tKbg=");   
FYI i need this key to pass in header but i am unable to do that.
and one more thing is i am using Jersey1.9 so ClientBuilder class doesnt exist in it. i am bound to use Jersey1.9 only 
please suggest some other solution. it will be immense help

Comment: I would first try to use a jersey client 2.x to address your 1.9 server. Now 1.9 is quite old, I never used it, but there is definitely a builder class, with some other name. Try checking the javadoc on a class named RessourceBuilder or similar. I'm pretty sure there is a method to set the header on the (old) builder class as well ...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried builder in Jersey 1.9 and its working fine. Thank for valueable input

Comment: You can add an upvote then :)